# notranslate class name doesn't work on Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, translate

To prevent some browsers to translate certain term on a HTML page, I use the `class="notranslate"` class name in a wrapping tag.

It works fine for Google Chrome with its built-in Google Translate plugin.
But it doesn't work with Microsoft Edge.

According to their documentation, it should.

I also tried the `translate="no"` property on the tag, without any success.

Any idea how to solve this?
If not, I would like to prevent auto-generated translations on Edge, but not on the other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add this line inside `<head></head>` to disable automatic translation in browser:

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```

I've tested and it can work well in Edge and Chrome.

---

**Edit:**

If you only want to restrict automatic translation in Edge only, you can add the `<meta>` tag dynamically. You can first check if the browser is Edge, if yes then add the tag. You can refer to the following JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edg') > -1) { //detect if Edge browser
        var meta = document.createElement('meta');
        meta.name = 'google';    
        meta.setAttribute('content', 'notranslate');    
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but this also disable the translation for Google Chrome. I would like to restrict it to Edge only.

Comment: @Bravo2bad Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have the feeling that Edge does not recognize the `notranslate` tag in general.

Answer (score 0):

The google tag for not translating the page has been updated to

```html
<meta name="googlebot" content="notranslate">
```

For more info check this link: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/special-tags

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Safari, Edge, and Chrome:

```
<html class='notranslate' translate='no'>

<head>
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <meta name="robots" content="notranslate">
    ...
</head>

<body translate="no" class="notranslate">
    ...
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's no need to MAKE THE END OF YOUR SENTENCE IN ALL CAPS.